# Best way to store mappings in a database

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, scalability, query-performance

Suppose I have an **employees** table(with around a million employees) and a **tasks** table(with a few hundred tasks).

Now, I have a mechanism to predict how probable(percentage) an employee is to complete the task -- let's say I have four such mechanisms, and each of the mechanism outputs it's own probability.

Putting it all together, I now have n1(employees) times n2(tasks) times n3(mechanisms) results to store.

I was wondering what would be the best way to store these results.

I have a few options and thoughts:

- Maintain a column(JSONField) in either of **employees** or **tasks** tables -- Concern: Have to update the whole column data if one of the values changes
- Maintaining a third table **predictions** with foreign keys to *employee* and *task* with a column to store the *predicted_probability* -- Concern: Will have to store n1 * n2 * n3 records, I'm worried about scalability and performance

Thanks for any help.

PS: I'm using Django with postgres

Comment: Stored Procedures maybe?

Comment: The `predictions` table is the correct way to go. Depending on how you _access_ the data, the size of the table won't matter. e.g. I would expect that reading the prediction for a single employee has a pretty constant performance. Large tables tend to be a problem only when you need to process all (or a large fraction) of the rows. _If_ you hit a performance problem once you test this, you could e.g. partition that table by task or by task and mechanism (depending on how your queries are structured)

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  for your comment. 
Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @Tomm how do you intend to use stored procedures in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `predictions` table is the correct way to go. Depending on how you access the data, the size of the table won't matter. e.g. I would expect that reading the prediction for a single employee has a pretty constant performance. Large tables tend to be a problem only when you need to process all (or a large fraction) of the rows. If you hit a performance problem once you test this, you could e.g. partition that table by task or by task and mechanism (depending on how your queries are structured)

-Credits to @a_horse_with_no_name